# iOS Video recorded using UIImagePickerController not getting deleted from Memory

Tags: ios, video-recording

I have an app which records multiple videos and show them to the user.
The user can also delete the recorded video.
I am recording the video using UIImagePickerController().
The recoded videos are saved in the default location which is "tmp".
When the user deletes the videos, I am deleting the video from videourl.Path. 
Somehow, the file is getting deleted from tmp folder, but the data is not getting released from the app.
So when the memory gets fulled, UIImagePickerController() doesn't allow the user to record the new videos, even though the video files are cleared from tmp folder.
There are no strong references to the video file urls.
Need help

Comment: Where you able to solve this ?

Comment: Nope. I am not able to solve this.